# Need help understanding Haskell id function

Tags: haskell, fold

Hello I have two versions of this function and I am having some trouble.

```
iter :: Int -> (a -> a) -> (a -> a)
iter n f
  | n > 0 = f . iter (n-1) f
  | otherwise = id

iter' :: Int -> (a -> a) -> (a -> a)
iter' n = foldr (.) id . replicate n
```

I cannot understand even after googling what does id actually do here.

Like for example if we come to the function with `n = 3` and `f x = x+1`.
When we iterate through the whole `n` and come to the point when `id` is being called what happens with our variables?

I am very big newbie so could you please explain as simplistically as possible.

Comment: This is a sorta complicated expression for a beginner to understand all at once. Maybe leave it for a while, and come back in a week or so. `id` isn't the problem: you probably understand quite well that it's the identity function, defined by `id x = x`. Rather you're looking at recursive composition of functions, which is tricky to get at first.

Comment: `id` is the identity for function composition, as `(f . id) x == (id . f) x == f x`, so it serves the same purpose as `0` for addition. Compare `foldr (.) id` to `foldr (+) 0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Summing a list `xs = [x1,x2,...,xn]` can be visualized as

```
x1 + x2 + ... + xn + 0
```

Note that `+ 0` at the very end. Its purpose is to handle the case where the list is empty, i.e. `xs = []` and `n=0`. In such case the sum above reduces to `0`, which is the correct sum for an empty list.

Also note that when the list is not empty the extra `+ 0` has no impact ont the sum, so it's harmless. We indeed choose `0` since it is the neutral element for addition: `x + 0 = x` for all `x`.

If we want to compute a product, we would write

```
x1 * x2 * ... * xn * 1
```

Note that `* 1` at the end. Its role is exactly the same as the `+ 0` seen above. Also note that `1` is the neutral element of multiplication: `x * 1 = x` for all `x`.

If we want to compute the composition of a list of functions, we would write

```
f1 . f2 . ... . fn . id
```

Note that `. id` at the end. Its role is exactly the same as the `+ 0` and `* 1` seen above. Also note that `id` is the neutral element of composition `f . id = f` for all `f`.

Hopefully this will help you understand why, every time we compute a fold like

```
x1 op x2 op ... op xn
```

where `op` is any binary operation, we want to end with `... op neutral_element` so to handle the empty list case, and still act as a good base case for non-empty lists.

Answer (score 1):

You can inline:

```
iter 3 f
f . iter 2 f
f . (f . iter 1 f)
f . (f . (f . iter 0 f)
f . (f . (f . id))

-- adding the argument x
iter 3 f x
(f . (f . (f . id))) x
-- using (g . h) x == g (h x)
f ((f . (f . id)) x)
f (f ((f . id) x))
f (f (f (id x)))
f (f (f x))
```

And in the case of `iter'`:

```
iter' 3 f
(foldr (.) id . replicate 3) f
foldr (.) id (replicate 3 f)
foldr (.) id [f, f, f]
(.) f (foldr (.) id [f, f]]
(.) f ((.) f (foldr (.) id [f]))
(.) f ((.) f ((.) f (foldr (.) id [])))
(.) f ((.) f ((.) f id))
f . (f . (f . id))
```